# Count occurance of an item in a list and store it in another list if it is exists more than once

Tags: python, pandas, list

Let's say I have the following list.

`my_list = ['4/10', '8/-', '9/2', '4/11', '-/13', '19/10', '25/-', '26/-', '4/12', '10/16']`

I would like to check the occurrence of each item and if it exists more than once I would like to store it in a new list.

For example from the above list, `4` is existed 3 times before `/` as `4/10, 4/11, 4/12`.  So I would like to create a new list called new list and store them as `new_list = '4/10', '4/11', '4/12, 19/10'`.

An additional example I want to consider also `/`. if `10` exist twice as `4/10 and 10/16` I don want to consider it as a duplicate since the position after and before `/` is different.

If there any way to count the existence of an item in a list and store them in a new list?

I tried the following but got an error.

```
new_list = []
d =  Counter(my_list)
for v in d.items():
  if v > 1:
        new_list.append(v)
```

The error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: where did the `'19/10'` came from in the `new_list`?

Comment: What is the format of Counter objets ('itemName', 'Nboccurence')?

Comment: what happens if you have multiple of ones that exist more than one? Do you want to create a list for each? a list of lists?

Comment: Because there are ```4/10 and 19/10. 10 exists twice as ```-/10```.

Comment: does the same logic apply to the values after the `/`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, indeed. For example if ```10``` exist as ```4/10 and 10/16``` I don want to consider as a duplicate since the position is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.items()` is not what you think - it returns a list of key-value pairs (tuples), not sole values. You want to:

```
d =  Counter(node)
new_list = [ k for (k,v) in d.items() if v > 1 ]
```

Besides, I am not sure how `node` is related to `my_list` but I think there is some additional processing you didn't show.

**Update:** after reading your comment clarifying the problem, I think it requires two separate counters:

```
first_parts = Counter([x.split('/')[0] for x in my_list])
second_parts = Counter([x.split('/')[1] for x in my_list])
first_duplicates = { k for (k,v) in first_parts.items() if v > 1 and k != '-' }
second_duplicates = { k for (k,v) in second_parts.items() if v > 1 and k != '-' }
new_list = [ e for e in my_list if
e.split('/')[0] in first_duplicates or e.split('/')[1] in second_duplicates ]
```

Comment: with your solution I got list of ```['4', '10', '-']```. But I am expecting ```['4/10', '4/11', '4/12']```

Comment: This is becoming more and more complicated, but I think it now does exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think below code is quite self-explanatory. It will work alright. If you have any issues or need clarification, feel free to ask.

**NOTE :** This code is not very efficient and can be improved a lot. But will work allright if you are not running this on extremely large data.

```
my_list = ['4/10', '8/-', '9/2', '4/11', '-/13', '19/10', '25/-', '26/-', '4/12', '10/16']
frequency = {}; new_list = [];
for string in my_list:
    x = '';
    for j in string:
        if j == '/':
            break;
        x += j;
    if x.isdigit():
        frequency[x] = frequency.get(x, 0) + 1;

for string in my_list:
    x = '';
    for j in string:
        if j == '/':
            break;
        x += j;
    if x.isdigit():
        if frequency[x] > 1:
            new_list.append(string);

print(new_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help :  create a dict to contain the pairings and then extract the pairings that have a length more than one. [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) helps with aggregating data, based on the common keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
e = defaultdict(list)
m = [ent for ent in my_list if '-' not in ent]

for ent in m:
    front, back = ent.split('/')
    d[front].append(ent)
    e[back].append(ent)

new_list = []
for k,v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        new_list.extend(v)

for k,v in e.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        new_list.extend(v)

sortr = lambda x: [int(ent) for ent in x.split("/")]
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(set(new_list), key = sortr)

print(new_list)

['4/10', '4/11', '4/12', '19/10']
```